Run python function from command line
I have a python script which contains many functions.
Currently, I'm using the if statement to call the right function whereas  the function name is passed as argument.
import sys

def myfunction(mystring):
    print(mystring)

def myfunction2():
    print('This Function 2')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if (sys.argv[1] == 'myfunction'):
        myfunction('test myfunction')
    elif(sys.argv[1] == 'myfunction2'):
        myfunction2()
    elif ....

    

So, I just call
python.exe pyscript.py myfunction('test')

The command is fine, but is there a straighter way in python so that I can avoid the if statement and the rewriting of the function names in the script itself?

See the duplicate above. You should pass extra arguments as separate shell arguments, like python.exe pyscript.py myfunction test. You can then pass them to the function using f(*sys.argv[2:])…

you could keep it as dictionary funcs = {'myfunction': myfunction, ...} and later execute using string funcs["myfunction"](*sys.argv[2:]). It is simpler than if/else and it allows to add new functions to dictionary later - e.g. when you load functions from modules.

as I remember module Click (often used instead of argv) executes functions by strings in command line.

@furas: the dictionary is a much better solution. Thank you!
